# how to handle all special characters in HTML/php form that outputs to XML

Tags: php, html, xml

I have a little php/mysql app I put together that takes an input form and stores it in a MySQL database, and outputs the data as XML for consumption by a radio-playing hardware device.

The problem is ampersands and other characters. The user is taking descriptions of various radio stations, along with streaming URL or Playlist URL and pasting them into the form. Some radio stations are in non-english speaking countries (mostly French). I need to know what to do to preprocess these fields so that the XML that is generated is not corrupted, which breaks the external hardware app.

I assume that this should go into the php that is called when the form is submitted. I'm pretty sure the **htmlspecialchars** function should be used, but I'm not sure the best method, since I've hacked this together from a variety of sources:

UPDATE: Here is my current output code with some regex that cleans up the ampersands.

```
<?
include("HLN/manager/connect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM hln_stations ORDER BY orderid ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_num_rows ($result);
mysql_close();

$xml = new XMLWriter();

$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->setIndent(true);

$xml->startElement('channels');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $xml->startElement("channel");
     $xml->startElement("title");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['station_title']));
     $xml->endElement();
     $xml->startElement("descriptionline1");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['station_display_name']));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->startElement("descriptionline2");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['station_subtitle']));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->startElement("description");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['station_detailed_description']));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->startElement("sdimage");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['sdtv_thumbnail_graphic_url']));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->startElement("hdimage");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['hdtv_thumbnail_graphic_url']));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->startElement("uri");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['stream_url_or_playlist_url']));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->startElement("linktype");
          $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;',$row['link_type']));
     $xml->endElement();

 $xml->endElement();
}

$xml->endElement();


$xml->flush();

?>
```

But I still need to solve the French character set issues that are cropping up. How can I replace the é character for example with something that doesn't cause problems?

Comment: Store the data as raw as possible and perform transformations during the output phase. Also, please see [`mysql_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Comment: ... and [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've an error in Firefox, that says not well formed, because the character set detected doesn't match the character set you output. I tried various combinations of character sets and could reproduce the issue.

You've to specify explicitly your character sets, such as:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
```

If specifying character set as UTF-8 in the content type and in XML gives you error, it means that your input is not valid UTF-8, try with ISO-8859-15 instead, or recode your input.

You have to put the content-type charset header for every page of your site, including the form to input data or your special characters could be messed up. Further you've to connect to mysql specifying the character set that you want to use for the connection and that should match the charset and collation of your tables.

Supposing that you're using UTF-8 look at your database with PHPMyAdmin and a UTF-8 connection, if you can't see your special characters well it means you're doing something wrong.

As for the device, if you say that it can display only ASCII characters, does it do the conversion for you when you give UTF-8 input or do you have to give the entity such as:

```
Ch&#xE9;rie
```

If those two options doesn't work, you may want to convert to ASCII, such as "Cherie"... but that would be the last resort.

---

Proof of concept code without using the DB:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

$radioArr = array(
   array("Chérie FM @Work", "http://www.listenlive.eu/cheriefm_atwork.m3u?p&test"), 
   array("Hélène FM", "http://broadcast.infomaniak.ch/helenefm-high.mp3.m3u")
);
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml->setIndent(true);
$xml->startElement('channels');
foreach ($radioArr AS $radio) {
     $xml->startElement("channel");

     $xml->startElement("title");
     $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;', $radio[0]));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->startElement("uri");
     $xml->writeRaw(preg_replace('/&(?![A-Za-z0-9#]{1,7};)/','&amp;', $radio[1]));
     $xml->endElement();

     $xml->endElement(); //end channel
}

$xml->endElement();
$xml->flush();

?>
```

Comment: Device can accept utf-8 in XML, but can only display ASCII characters on screen. Here is a string that causes problems: Nous vous souhaitons la plus cordiale bienvenue sur le site de la Radio Shalom Fm. Nous sommes une station évangélique et nous sommes ouverts 24/24. Nous vous offrons une programmation diversifiée axée sur trois grands fondements évangéliques à savoir: la prière, l’enseignement et l’évangélisation

Comment: well ASCII is the 0-127 character range and doesn't include any accented letter, so if it can really only accept ASCII the only thing you could do is transform accented letters in their basic counterpart. Are you sure about that? What about using unicode? Would it work with this "Ch&#xE9;rie"?

Comment: I tried your string and at least in Firefox works without problems.

Comment: Content type on all forms is: content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1. PhpMYAdmin is UTF-8 connection, the é shows there if I paste it into a field, and, even with the added xml header and startdocument that you suggested, I still get the error if I put that character into a field in the form.

Comment: *"Content type on all forms is: content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1. PhpMYAdmin is UTF-8 connection, the é shows there if I paste it into a field"* --> this confirms my worries, your DB data is saved in UTF-8 but you got from the user as ISO-8859-1. If you choose ISO-8859-1 is fine, but then you've to use it in the headers, instead of my UTF-8 example and PHPMyAdmin should show correctly with an ISO-8859-1 connection, otherwise you're messing your encodings!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to really "clean up french characters" (remove)

What about doing this ([iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)) ?

```
iconv('utf8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
```

Comment: That still gives: XML Parsing Error: not well-formed in Firefox, which, while it is not the destination, tells me it isn't going to work on the device.

Comment: alphablender: this should remove all diacritics character if your input is in UTF8. Maybe the input is not UTF8 but iso8859-1? Try to detect the original encoding (with iconv) and then convert it to ASCII, should work

Answer (score 3):

Wrapped the data using CDATA. Instead of **writeRaw()** use **writeCData()**
Please refer to the sample below.

```
// CData output
$xml->startElement('title');
$xml->writeCData($row['station_subtitle']);
$xml->endElement();
```

Comment: Firefox throws and error and so does my app, Firefox: output:XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://myserver.com/teststations.php
Line Number 79, Column 123:  <description>Nous vous souhaitons la plus cordiale bienvenue sur le site de la Radio Shalom Fm. Nous sommes une station vanglique et nous sommes ouverts 24/24. Nous vous offrons une programmation diversifie axe sur t
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^

Comment: can you post the resulting XML the one using CDATA?

Comment: this is working on my end:

<title>
<![CDATA[Nous vous souhaitons la plus cordiale bienvenue sur le site de la Radio Shalom Fm. Nous sommes une station évangélique et nous sommes ouverts 24/24. Nous vous offrons une programmation diversifiée axée sur trois grands fondements évangéliques à savoir: la prière, l’enseignement et l’évangélisation]]>
</title>

Comment: wrapped everything in CDATA, on top of making sure all my forms were utf-8, and that seems to do the job, so thank you for your help also.